# JMS Client Standalone Java Program

Tags: java, jms

I would like to use a standalone java program to poll and retrieve messages from JMS queue instead of having an MDB. Is it possible?

If it is, would it be possible to share any examples / links? Thanks.

Regards,V

Comment: "MDB" and "standalone java program" are not mutually exclusive. You'll need to better explain what you're looking for.

Comment: Unless by "MDB" you mean the EJB MDB? If so, see my answer.

Comment: What provider do you use for JMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the other response that Spring JMS is simple (providing you know a bit of Spring, and have the framework) but it's quite straightforward from plain old Java too. Just write some code within main to setup a ConnectionFactory, Connection, and Session, e.g. see

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS4.html

you can either look up a ConnectionFactory from JNDI or instantiate a provider-specific one yourself; e.g. for WebSphere MQ you would write something like:

```
MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
cf.setPort(PORT);
cf.setChannel(CHANNEL);
cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

(other providers are available, I just can't write the code off the top of my head :) then standard JMS

```
Connection c = cf.createConnection();
Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue q = s.createQueue("myQueue");
MessageConsumer c = s.createConsumer(q);
```

at this point you have two options. You could create a javax.jms.MessageListener implementation and set it on the MessageConsumer, or if you want more direct control you can either kick off a Thread that uses the MessageConsumer to do either a get-with-wait (receive(int timeout)) or a get with no wait (receiveNoWait()) and then a sleep until the next receive. Don't use receive() though, it's never a good idea with JMS. If you want more than one polling thread then you should check the concurrency restrictions on JMS Session/Consumer objects.

Don't forget to call Connection.start() once the setup is done if you want anything to happen

Advantages are you only need your JMS provider .jars on the classpath, no framework etc. Disadvantages are that it's more complex than Spring, which provides quite an elegant solution to this - note how much setup code there is here, compared to Spring which abstracts it all out. Really depends on your preferences, other requirements etc.

Comment: Thank You very much. Appreciate your detailed response :-)

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest way I know to consume JMS messages is with [Spring JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html). In particular, using the [Spring JMS namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace), it can be as simple as:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="aJmsConnectionFactory">
    <jms:listener destination="someQueue" ref="theBeanToDelegateTo" method="theMethodToInvoke"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

which will consume from "someQueue" and pass the messages to the bean named "theBeanToDelegateTo", method "theMethodToInvoke", converting messages to Java types as specified by [SimpleMessageConverter](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.4/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/SimpleMessageConverter.html).

**Edit:** I've just created a sample project on github that does exactly what you're asking. Browse the source at https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/basic-spring-jms or clone and run it:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=rds.jms.Main -pl basic-spring-jms
```

It's a total of two classes--could have just been one, but two felt cleaner--and it handles starting and stopping both a JMS broker and a Spring container. There's a main class that starts things and waits for the user to shut it down. When Spring starts, it inits a bean that begins sending JMS messages. There's also a Spring message listener as I described above that consumes messages and passes them to that same bean, which prints them to stdout.

Comment: Am I right in saying that I would have use spring framework and some sort of an application server to use Spring JMS? Is it possible to just have a class having a 'main' method to consume messages from a JMS Queue?

Comment: @Vicky: No, that's not right--no server needed. In your main method, just `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("whatever spring context file");` and Spring is running. If you don't want to start Spring for whatever reason, you could also just instantiate and configure a [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) yourself, though it's a bit more work.